# How can I post the same question on a Team and "public" Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

After creating a private Team on Stack Overflow, how can I post the same question on the Team as well as publicly? Is that possible?

Answer (score 9):

You can't. Teams are *fundamentally* separated out from the public site.

Its meant for 'private' Q&A and there's no way to *automatically* crosspost.

You'd need to do it manually and since teams have a looser set of moderation standards... you would just copy paste the teams question to public Q&A, then link back the public Q&A question for reference

Comment: that's a bummer. So when your product is commercial open-source and you need to share the knowledge to the community, but keep some solutions private then Stack for Teams is not the solution.